# Installing opencv on Ubuntu 16-04

Tags: python, opencv, virtualenv

I have a `virtualenv` created with `virtualenvwrapper`.

However, I'm on python 2.7

Whenever I try to install the `opencv-python` by `pip`, as `sudo` or not, I receive this message:

```
pip install opencv-python
Downloading/unpacking opencv-python
Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement opencv-python
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for opencv-python
Storing debug log for failure in /home/kristian/.pip/pip.log
```

Any ideas on why this us happening?

Comment: I am using 2.7.6 and this gets installed as normal

Comment: `sudo apt-get install python-opencv` try this.

Comment: Is still usable on a python virtual environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pip is most likely too old since opencv-python packages are distributed as manylinux1 wheels (https://github.com/pypa/manylinux). You need pip version 8.1 or later to install manylinux1 binary packages.

To upgrade your pip globally:

```
sudo -H pip install --upgrade pip
```

Inside virtualenv this should be enough:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

Comment: Loool, super awesome, that did it! Thank You very much!

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use [anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/download/), which is very convenient and saves a lot of trouble. With anaconda, you don't need to care about your local environment.